# How to send magic package to windows xp

Tags: wakeonlan

Hi Is there a program which can send magic package to wake on lan Windows XP computer ? Or can it be done thru command line.

Answer (score 1):

See [WakeOnLan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan).

Command line package names:

```
powerwake
wakeonlan
etherwake
```

GUI software:

```
gwakeonlan
```

Comment: I understood he wants to use an Ubuntu host to send the wake-up packet to another computer (incidentially running Windows XP, but since wake on LAN is received at the BIOS level the remote OS should not be relevant).

Comment: yes this is what I want to do send from ubuntu to windows